# Rails Serializer for Devise User model not being used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, response, serialization

Here's the response my Rails app is giving me:

```
{"users":[{"users":{"id":20,"email":"subscriber@email.com", ...
```

Here's what it should looks like (this is for another working resource):

```
{"companies":[{"id":448,"name":"Microsoft Security ...
```

Notice the wrapping `users:` object.

Here's my Serializer for the User model:

```
class UserSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id,
             :first_name,
             :last_name
end
```

And for the Company model:

```
class CompanySerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id, :name
end
```

What am I missing? What I need to do so the json response uses this UserSerializer class?

```
def index
  load_users
  render json: @users
end
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of `@users`?

Comment: I'm using Devise, and I think that mucks about with the serializer, though I'm not sure how to fix the problem.

Comment: If you do `pp @users` right before the render, what do you get?

Comment: This https://gist.github.com/sergiotapia/2c5352b8cfb866b12508 - It's a problem with the Serializer not being picked up. I've double checked the filename (serializers/user_serializer.rb), the class name (UserSerializer) - I'm pretty sure it's Devise and I don't know what to override.

Comment: Did you create `SubscriberSerializer < UserSerializer`, `PublisherSerializer < UserSerializer`, etc...?

Comment: Downvoter, why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

I knew it was a problem with Rails somehow ignoring my Serializer.

In my controller I wrote this:

```
# app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:

class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  def default_serializer_options
    { each_serializer: UserSerializer } # I use each_serializer instead of serializer because it's rendering a collection.
  end
end
```

Basically I man-handled the code to use the right serializer and it's working fine now.